# Induced Voltage in Induction Motor

Tags: induction-motor

[image: Magnetic Fields in Induction Motor]

It is an image of a squirrel cage rotor. \$\textbf{B}_{S}\$ is the rotating magnetic field created by the stator. It creates an induced voltage \$\textbf{E}_{S}\$(not shown in the image) in the bars of the rotor. The plane of maximum \$E_{S}\$ is the plane containing \$\textbf{B}_{S}\$. \$\textbf{E}_{S}\$ creates the rotor current \$\textbf{I}_{R}\$ which produces another magnetic field \$\textbf{B}_{R}\$. The net magnetic field \$\textbf{B}_{net}\$ induces a voltage \$\textbf{E}_{R}\$.Will \$\textbf{E}_{R}\$ produce another current which will add with \$\textbf{I}_{R}\$? How does this process end?

Comment: Explain how you can say "It creates an induced voltage in the bars of the rotor aligned with \$B_S\$."

Comment: Explanation is given in the post.